# asyncio.gather not executing tasks when caller function requests input from STDIN?

Tags: python, input, concurrency, task, python-asyncio

In the following contrived example I am attempting to get input from STDIN and execute a list of coroutine tasks concurrently using `asyncio.gather` based on the input from STDIN.:

```
import asyncio

async def task_1():
    print('task_1!')

async def task_2():
    print('task_2!')

async def task_3():
    print('task_3!')

async def task_4():
    print('task_4!')

async def main():
    opts = {
        '1': [task_1, task_2],
        '2': [task_3, task_4]
    }
    while True:
        opt = input('Enter option: ')
        tasks = opts.get(opt)
        asyncio.gather(t() for t in tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

However when executing the above code the output does not contain the desired output when the corresponding option is entered.

Input '1' from STDIN should print to STDOUT:

```
task_1!
task_2!
```

Input '2' from STDIN should print to STDOUT:

```
task_2!
task_3!
```

When entering either '1' or 'two' there's no output. Why aren't any of the `tasks` being executed by `asyncio.gather`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await the asyncio, and you need to pass it multiple arguments, not a list.

```
await asyncio.gather(*(t() for t in tasks))
```

Comment: this is not the the main problem there: the problem is that "input" stops the program synchronously before "gather" is reached.

Comment: @jsbueno.  Worked fine when I ran it.

Comment: indeed, the OP is not complaining about what I thought he was.

Comment: @jsbueno.  Yeah, been there.